# Are maximizing the log probability and assigning the ground-truth token the highest rank the same?

Tags: likelihood, natural-language, loss-functions, log-loss

I have been reading this paper titled [Neural Text Generation with Unlikelihood Training](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.04319). It is about the maximum likelihood function used to train generative models. Anyway, it says that a major flaw of the likelihood objective is that it pays relatively little attention to the argmax or the top of the ranked list of next token probabilities, instead optimizing the likelihood of the entire distribution. In other words, there is a discrepancy between maximizing the log-probability of a ground-truth token and ensuring the rank of the ground-truth token to be one.

Now, why would that be? My understanding is that if your model assigns the highest probability to the ground-truth token, the loss will automatically be minimized (I am considering the loss function to be cross-entropy loss) so where is the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because cross-entropy measures the Kullback-Leibler divergence of your entire distribution of discrete next token probabilities (to an implicit ground truth distribution).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy

Now, normally we are optimizing the MLE described in formula (1) of the paper. So, as to a binary answer to the question in the headline itself: yes, they are the same. I.e., maximizing the log probability described in formula (4) (and 5) of the paper is at least a pretty reasonable approximation of assigning the ground-truth token the highest rank.

Comment: Yes but isn't the way to minimize the KL divergence to assign the maximum probability to the ground truth token?

Comment: The authors are complaining that with CE (aka "perplexity") you are optimizing against the "entire distribution", which is the (training set) language that is assumed to be stationary & ergodic. While the authors would want "the rank of the ground-truth token to be [explicitly set to] one" - which is quite different than maximizing the (log-) probability of that token.

Comment: Maybe this phrase from official review of the paper here helps, too: "The unlikelyhood training is to provide a set of negative candidates and minimize the probability of these tokens." [https://openreview.net/forum?id=SJeYe0NtvH&noteId=ryeEqCDG5B] Which is also not explicitly setting the rank to one, but at least implicitly, by trying to "remove" the negative candidates from the regular MLE (cf. formula (1) and (4) in the paper).

Comment: So the CE loss is explicitly trying to maximize the negative log probability of the ground-truth token but it might not be one. Let's assume it does become one, then would there still be a discrepancy?

Comment: If you just want my binary answer to the question in your headline, given what we said so far: *yes* - assuming you mean maximizing the log probability described in formula (4) (and 5) of the paper.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome! I've updated my answer accordingly; Hope you will consider this the correct answer you sought.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You actually went through  a paper for an answer. I'm really grateful for this.

Comment: You're welcome; If you think my answer is correct, would you mind "ticking" it as such - or let me know if you still have doubts?

Comment: I did but because I'm new on stackexchange, my upvotes don't count.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting, but that is not what I mean. As the user asking a question, you can accept one answer as the correct one, if you consider that answer has resolved your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Got it. Done. Thanks a lot.